# IOS NSDate does not format correctly

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two NSDate objects

one in this format

`yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`

the other one is in

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Is there any difference between them?

I also tried to convert the second format one to the first format, but for some reason, I can get it to the correct NSString but not in NSDate, NSDate always show as yyyy-MM-dd, I cannot find the reason to it.

here is the code i did to convert from - to :

```
//photo date has this date 2013-07-21 18:02:13
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:photoDate];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@":"];
NSDateFormatter *converter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[converter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate * newPhotoDate = [converter dateFromString:dateString];
// newPhotoDate still has it in 2013-07-21 18:02:13 but dateString actually is in 2013:07:21 18:02:13
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: NSDate is a number. It has no formatting.

Comment: if i do nslog i see that 2013-07-21 18:02:13 and 2013:07:21 18:02:13

Comment: BTW `NSString * newPhotoDate = [converter dateFromString:dateString];`  is wrong. `dateFromString:` returns `NSDate` not `NSString`

Comment: `NSDate` is a wrapper for an `NSTimeInterval` nothing more, nothing less. It is an absolute point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDate is an **date object** there is ***no formatting*** on the object.Formats comes for getting the string value from NSDate so that **we can present in what way we want**.What ever format it may be NSDate remains the same

Eg

I/P

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@",date);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString =[df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);


[df setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:yyyy"];
dateString =[df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

O/P

```
2013-07-26 12:47:08.727 Trial[4191:11303] 2013-07-26 07:17:08 +0000
2013-07-26 12:47:08.728 Trial[4191:11303] 26-07-2013
2013-07-26 12:47:08.731 Trial[4191:11303] 26:07:2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to Convert `NSString` to `NSDate`;

Such Like..

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-7-12 12:22:51";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date : %@", date);
```